# username password saved in browser issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-ui

There is a kendo grid inline add with toolbar add new record. In our system if we logged in and save our user name and password in browser, then user name and password adding grid text boxes also autamatically filled with that logged in user's username and password.. why is that happen? What is the sollution?

Comment: Dump some code here.

Comment: it's the browser autocomplete on that inputs, change inputs name and id in add new record.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are describing seems to be the normal behaviour of the browser's autocomplete.  If you want the browser to ignore the autocomplete for a specific input, set the `autocomplete` attribute value to `off`:

```
<input name="myInput" type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```